# Kotlin function override null check

Tags: kotlin, android-location, kotlin-null-safety

I try to get lastLocation of user and implemented the method like this.

```
getLocationClient()?.lastLocation?.addOnSuccessListener(object :
               OnSuccessListener<Location> {
           override fun onSuccess(loc: Location) {
               if (loc == null) return
              }
       })
```

But when I don't add null safety to parameter Location in onSuccess method, that causes some crashes when Location parameter is null.

When I add null safety to the parameter like in the image below, it doesn't override the method. I was able to override this method with null safety but something changed i guess.

[image]

How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: This sounds like one of those cases where you're interacting with Java code that's not properly annotated for nullability, and so the Kotlin compiler can't ensure null safety. If so, then an explicit null check, like the first code block, may be the best approach (even though it may give you warnings). Or, equivalently, handle the null case later on, using `?:` or `?.` or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type parameter for OnSuccessListener needs to be nullable too, i.e. `OnSuccessListener<Location?>` instead of `OnSuccessListener<Location>`

```
getLocationClient()?.lastLocation?.addOnSuccessListener(object :
               OnSuccessListener<Location?> {
           override fun onSuccess(loc: Location?) {
               if (loc == null) return
              }
       })
```

BTW, you can also use the [SAM](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html) syntax for a shorter way of doing the same thing:

```
getLocationClient()?.lastLocation?.addOnSuccessListener { loc: Location? ->
    if (loc == null) return
}
```